# Storing CHAR(9) in SQL columns

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL table in which I have a column `COLA` of type `CHAR(1)`. I am trying to insert `CHAR(9)` into this column and I get this error:

> String or binary data would be truncated in table

But when I make the column of type `CHAR(6)`, it works.

Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: Because the trimmed values from the char(9) you insert into the char(6) only have 6 or less characters?

Comment: Cannot reproduce - I can insert `CHAR(9)` into a `CHAR(1)` column - no problem. You need to show us **(1)** DDL for your table, and **(2)** the SQL used to do the insert

Comment: Don't know about Azure Sql Database. But f.e. in MS Sql Server the trailing spaces don't matter for the insert in a CHAR. And LEN doesn't count the trailing spaces from a CHAR.  
 *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2db82d6780cddd21fc36eb15f74ea62f)*

Answer (score 0):

> Error - String or binary data would be truncated in table

This error generally occurs, when we try to insert more data into a column than the specified column can store.

In your case you are able to insert CHAR(9) to CHAR(6) maybe because column CHAR(9) has values less than or equal to 6 or white spaces at the end of char are not considered.